# quiero ocultar los botones si hay menos de 50 palabras y no consigo hacerlo. La función ocultacion() no los oculta. ¿por qué?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#b_ocultar").hide("fast");

});

function mostrar(){
    $("#texto").show("slow");
    $("#b_mostrar").hide("fast");
    $("#b_ocultar").show("fast");

    }

function ocultar(){
    $("#texto").hide("slow");
    $("#b_ocultar").hide("fast");
    $("#b_mostrar").show("fast");

}
    function ocultacion(){


    $("#b_mostrar").hide("fast");
    $("#b_ocultar").hide("fast");

}




<div>
<?php
//------------------------para el texto que aparece y se esconde----------------------

$array=explode(" ",utf8_decode($fila3['descripcion']));//guardamos las palabras con separación de espación

//con un for mostramos las palabras que queremos
if(count($array)<50){//por si tiene memos de 50 palabras

    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        echo $array[$i] . " ";//para espaciar las palabras

    }

?>

<script language='javascript'>ocultacion();</script>

<?php   

}else{//si tiene más de 50 palabras

    for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
        echo $array[$i] . " ";
    }
echo "...";//para que lo muestre si tiene más de 50 palabras
}

?>
</div>
<div  id="texto" style="display:none">
<?php
//muestra el resto del texto dentro del div
for($i=50;$i<count($array);$i++){
    echo $array[$i] . " ";
    }

?>
</div>
<!--------------------fin del texto-------------------------------------------->

<br>
<!---------------------botones de mostrar más y mostrar menos texto------------------------->
<button onClick="mostrar()" id="b_mostrar" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Mostrar m&aacute;s...</button>
<button onClick="ocultar()" id="b_ocultar" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Mostrar menos...</button>
</br></br>
```

Comment: Hola Jesus. Por favor no pongas solo el codigo. Explica qué errores o problemas concretos tienes y cual es el resultado esperado. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Ocultar qué botones? ¿Si hay menos de 50 palabras dónde? ¿A partir de qué evento quieres hacer eso (el click de un botón, el cambio en un input text, la selección de una opción en un select, simplemente cuando se cargue la página? Sin esos datos es imposible poder ayudarte.

Comment: Posiblemente no los oculta porque el script se está ejecutando antes de la creación de los botones. Además esta es una forma algo rara de ejecutar el script ¿Por qué no usas el evento ready() de document en Javascript en lugar de que PHP haga la llamada?

Comment: Al llamar la función así: <script language='javascript'>ocultacion();</script> el DOM no está listo y por tanto, aún no existe #b_mostrar o #b_ocultar. Deberías asegurarte que llamas la función cuando el DOM esté ready, por ejemplo, al body onload: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta me me ayudó a solucionarlo if(count($array)<50){//por si tiene memos de 50 palabras

 for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
  echo $array[$i] . " ";//para espaciar las palabras

 }

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    ocultacion();
});


</script>

<?php 
 
}else{//si tiene más de 50 palabras
 
 for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
  echo $array[$i] . " ";
 }
echo "...";//para que lo muestre si tiene más de 50 palabras
}

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser por los siguientes temas:

1. Tenés el tag `<script>` mal cerrado, no veo nunca que al principio se cierre, sólo veo un `<div>` y después ponés la función php.
2. `<script language="javascript">` es demasiado viejo y está deprecado, lo ideal es usar `<script type="text/javascript">` que es el standard de *HTML 4*.
3. Cuando llamás a `ocultacion();` los botones aún no están renderizados. Lo más conveniente es llamarlo una vez que termine el renderizado del DOM.

HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ocultacion();
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo solucioné.

Comment: Buenísimo, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta.